# Connecting slots and signals between a class instance and a dialog within another class instance

Tags: c++, qt, hierarchy

I am writing a program in QT, which currently has a `GameEngine` (data handling) class and a `MainWindow` (GUI) class.

The single instances of both `GameEngine`and `MainWindow` classes are owned by the `int main` function.

The `MainWindow` instance has a `User Action`-button, which will open an instance of a QDialog class called `Dialog_UserAction`. The instance of this QDialog is owned by the `MainWindow`, which is also the parent of the QDialog (to disable the `MainWindow` GUI while the `Dialog_UserAction` instance is open).

My issue is that many events (signals) need to be connected between the QDialog and the `GameEngine` instance.

Is there any simple way that I can achieve this?

I have already tried by forwarding the signals from `Dialog_UserAction` to `GameEngine` via the `MainBoard` and vice versa. This works, but it is quite a messy solution for this task.

I have also tried letting the `Dialog_UserAction` be owned by `Main`, but I don't know how to react on the `User Action Button clicked`-event in main context.

Finally, I have also tried letting the `Dialog_UserAction` be owned by the `GameEngine` instance, which would the easy solution (except that the `MainBoard` GUI will not be disabled, while `Dialog_UserAction` is opened). But, I would really prefer that all GUI related instances were kept out of the `GameEngine` context.

> GameEngine.h:

```
class GameEngine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void someSignalToDialog(void);

public slots:
    void on_someSignalFromDialog();
}
```

> Dialog_UserAction.h:

```
class Dialog_UserAction: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void someSignalToGameEngine(void);

public slots:
    void on_someSignalFromGameEngine();
}
```

> Main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/MageKnightLogo.jpg"));
    GameEngine gameEngine;
    Window_MainBoard mainBoard;

    mainBoard.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```

> MainBoard.cpp:

```
#include "Dialog_UserAction.h"

...

void Window_MainBoard::on_pushButton_enterUserAction_clicked() {
    Dialog_UserAction actionDialog(this);

    // connect signals and slots here?

    if (actionDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        // Send signal with data to GameEngine
    }
}
...
```

So, what I'm really asking is:
Is there any simple way I can setup the signal-slot connections in this setup where I can connect `Dialog_UserAction` with `GameEngine` without forwarding the signals in the `MainBoard` context?

If not, do you have any suggestions on how I could approach this in a better way in general? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you really don't want the game engine to worry about the existence of the dialog. So just put the signals you need into the main window, and connect them once to the game engine. Then when your dialog is created, connect its signals to main window's signals. Writing helper functions to do this would help your code remain readable. I don't see what your issue with this approach is, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `GameEngine` object is a singleton (only one instance exists), you can have the `Dialog_UserAction` object connect its signals directly to the `GameEngine` object. You can do that in the `Dialog_UserAction` constructor.

To get easy access to the `GameEngine` object, simply add a static member function to it that returns a static `GameEngine*` member.

> GameEngine.h

```
class GameEngine
{
public:
    GameEngine()
    {
        Q_ASSERT(instance_ == nullptr); // Only one instance allowed.
        instance_ = this;
    }

    static GameEngine* instance() noexcept
    { return instance_; }

private:
    static GameEngine* instance_;
};
```

> GameEngine.cpp

```
GameEngine* GameEngine::instance_ = nullptr;
```

You can now connect the `Dialog_UserAction` signals to `GameEngine::instance()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Singleton was indeed the keyword I needed. Never heard of it before. I am an electronics engineer and only programming this for fun in my spare time.
The only thing I think is missing from your answer above, is where the call to the constructor of GameEngine is!?
I ended using the Lazy Initialization method by performing the " == nullptr" check in the instance() method.

Comment: @Jesperten I usually create such objects in `main()` right before the `QApplication::exec()` call.

Comment: Okay, I didn't think of that. I have posted my own answer below. I hope that you could take some time to read it through and comment, if there is anything I have misunderstood :-)
Anyway, I've got it running and working now. So thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, just for clarification, I ended using the Singleton design pattern as suggested by Nikos C.

But I implemented the class a little differently, and therefore wanted to share this as a standalone answer.

I found that I needed to trigger the constructor of the the object somehow, and figured that this could be done using the so-called (I believe) Lazy Initialization method. Also, the constructor of the class should be private, such that only the instance itself will be able to call this, and thus making sure that the constructor is only called once.

Furthermore, I made the `GameEngine::Instance()`method as a `const static GameEngine*`-type in order to let the access to the object be read-only.

> GameEngine.h

```
class GameEngine
{

public:
    const static GameEngine* instance() { // Singleton instance reference getter
        if (instance_ == nullptr)
            instance_ = new GameEngine(); // This triggers the constructor of the object
        return instance_;
    }

private:
    GameEngine(); // The constructor is made private!
};
```

> GameEngine.cpp

```
// Place this declaration in the top of the file to create the global class instance pointer
// The initial value of the pointer must be nullptr to let the constructor be correctly triggered at the first instance()-call
GameEngine* GameEngine::instance_ = nullptr;
```

Then in `Main` and `Dialog_UserAction` (the clients) the access to the Singleton GameEngine instance is used by creating a const class instance pointer in the each context.

> Main.cpp

```
#include "GameEngine.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window_MainBoard mainBoard;

    const GameEngine* gameEngine = GameEngine::instance(); // Const pointer to the Singleton instance of the GameEngine class (global object)

    QObject::connect(gameEngine, SIGNAL(someSignalToDialog), &mainBoard, SLOT(on_someSignalFromGameEngine));
}
```

> Dialog_UserAction.cpp

```
#include "GameEngine.h"

// Constructor
Dialog_UserAction::Dialog_UserAction(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog_UserAction) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Const pointer to the Singleton instance of the GameEngine class (global object)
    const GameEngine* gameEngine = GameEngine::instance();

    connect(this, SIGNAL(someSignalToGameEngine), gameEngine, SLOT(on_someSignalFromDialog)                                                                );
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for the pointer to be `const`. Also, the `connect()` calls you're using are deprecated (they're from Qt 4, only there for compatibility with very old code.) You should use the Qt 5 `connect()` functions: `connect(this, &Dialog_UserAction::someSignalToGameEngine, gameEngine, &GameEngine::on_someSignalFromDialog));` The new functions allow the signal/slot connections to be checked during compilation. The old functions are string-based, and the connections are only checked during run-time (meaning wrong connections will compile fine and only fail when the application runs.)

Comment: If you're using Qt Creator as your IDE, you can right-click on a `connect()` call and select "Refactor->Convert connect to Qt 5 style". This might not work in every case, so sometimes you need to do it manually.